# Why does Android Studio auto generate the onCreateView as nullable, then prompts to remove it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This question is more out of curiosity than is is out of a bug or something else.

When I generate a blank fragment from the Android Studio templates, the *onCreateView* method which returns a View, has the nullable question mark. The Android Studio highlights it in yellow and tips to remove the nullable sign since the *onCreateView* return a non nullable View.

Why doesn't Android Studio autogenerate it as non nullable from the start? Is it a bug or intentional? If intentional, why?

Comment: `Why doesn't Android Studio autogenerate it as non nullable from the start?` no idea, but perhaps it is generating off of what is available for java ?

Comment: `Is it a bug` but on the top you mentioned `more out of curiosity than is is out of a bug`? If you want to report this as a bug, why not use the issue tracker by google?

Comment: I'm a noob at posting in the community, so thank you for your advice. Didn't report as bug because I don't know if it is really a bug or not. Although, it doesn't seem as a bug, considering @Pawel 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing - returning `null` from `onCreateView` is perfectly fine in order to create a "headless fragment" but those are not really useful since viewmodels were introduced.

This might be a reason why `onCreateView` return type is nullable but if you do override it then it's implied you want to return something from it so studio can only drop a hint.

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank you!